How can I make AWS Elastic Beanstalk logs readable?
I just deployed to AWS - Elastic Beanstalk and found the logs undreadable.  These are the logs directly downloaded from Elastic Beanstalk Environment GUI.
Particularly, there is an ELB-Healthchecker every few seconds, which drowns out any useful information.
Ideally, I would like to turn this HealthChecker off, as it has the opposite effect; it is making my job harder.
I could not find a tag for elastic beanstalk.
Brace your eyes but here is some example output.
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:48:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46" "185.16.39.118"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:49:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:50:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.36.118 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:51:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.13.194 - - [10/Sep/2024:12:51:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4051 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"

